# Algolia instant search react api keys and api id

Tags: reactjs, algolia, instantsearch

I'm trying to use Algolia react instant search in my react app and the documentation said that I need an API key and app id, how can I get those properties from my backend.

Answer (score 0):

For each "App" in your Algolia dashboard, you should see a navigation item on the left side that says "API Keys" This is where you'll find the App ID and the Search-only API key that you're looking for. Each one can be copied from that spot

[image: An image of the left-side navigation in the Algolia dashboard]